# vsync option not displayed on nvidia-settings 384.90

Tags: 16.04, drivers, kubuntu, xorg, nvidia-optimus

I've read most related questions and forum posts and haven't been able to solve this issue in more than a year.

I am running Kubuntu 16.04 on a Lenovo Y700, which has an Nvidia GTX 960M graphics card with Optimus technology (i.e. also an Intel gpu). Ever since I got this laptop, I have experienced tearing while moving windows, changing workspaces, watching videos, browsing the internet, playing games, etc.

I have tried running the following commands, but neither of them works:

```
nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="nvidia-auto-select +0+0 { ForceCompositionPipeline = On }"

nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="nvidia-auto-select +0+0 { ForceFullCompositionPipeline = On }"
```

Furthermore, as shown in the screenshot below, these options do not appear on my advanced NVIDIA XServer Settings, even though I'm using the version 384.90.

[image]

This issue might be related to the fact that neither the laptop screen nor the external monitor is recognised by nvidia-settings, i.e. it always shows "X Screen 0 (No Scanout)".

My /etc/X11/xorg.conf file looks like this:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "modesetting"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
    Option "AccelMethod" "None"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
    Option "ConstrainCursor" "off"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
    Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
EndSection
```

Any ideas as to how this could be solved?

Answer (score 1):

My Thread from a year ago and updated a few times - EASY PEASY

Screen Tearing Finally SOLVED! 4 Easy Steps and reduce Choppiness Too! and add VSync !

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2374405

Always Trying to help, Mark

Comment: Just tried this, but the output for "sudo cat /sys/module/nvidia_drm/parameters/modeset" after reboot is still "N".

Comment: I had to do it as suggested here (https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1027337/linux/how-to-enable-prime-synchronization-/) but I still get tearing with Prime.

Comment: Can you play this file without tearing? https://ubuntuforums.org/attachment.php?attachmentid=264973&d=1444947795